# How to simplify NgRx effects? Only difference the service method they call-

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have got the following code from an NgRx effects file:

```js
  registerUser$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthStoreActions.registerUser),
      switchMap(action => {
        return this.authService.registerWithEmailAndPassword(action.userCredentials).pipe(
          map(() => AuthStoreActions.authSuccess({ navigateTo: "authentication/restaurant" })),
          catchError(error => of(AuthStoreActions.setError({ error })))
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

```js
  loginUser$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthStoreActions.loginUser),
      switchMap(action => {
        return this.authService.loginWithEmailAndPassword(action.userCredentials).pipe(
          map(() => AuthStoreActions.authSuccess({ navigateTo: "authentication/restaurant" })),
          catchError(error => of(AuthStoreActions.setError({ error })))
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

After the service call both are doing the same thing. How could eleminate the repeatness?
I have got an other sibling effects aswell which does more after receiving the response from the server than this example, but apart from the method they call, they are doing the same thing.

Comment: Personally, I like your implementation. I know we should strive to be as DRY as possible, but I'm not sure that being DRY is always worth the complexity of the abstraction required to avoid it. I feel like keeping your effects this way is concise and it explicitly describes your workflow.

Comment: In this example it migth look acceptable because its just two lines, but the other one i have has 10 redundant lines.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `pipe` function, you can bottle up those auth store operators in one.

The power of function composition!

```js
import { pipe } from "rxjs";

const handleAuth = pipe(
  map(() => AuthStoreActions.authSuccess({ navigateTo: "authentication/restaurant" })),
  catchError(error => of(AuthStoreActions.setError({ error }))));

loginUser$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthStoreActions.loginUser),
    switchMap(action => this.authService.loginWithEmailAndPassword(action.userCredentials).pipe(handleAuth)));

registerUser$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthStoreActions.registerUser),
      switchMap(action => this.authService.registerWithEmailAndPassword(action.userCredentials).pipe(handleAuth)));
```

Comment: A bit misleading that it is called authSuccess, but it encloses the catchError side. Other than that it seems good.

Comment: I wait a few days to see what the people view of it, if there wont be better idea than i will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, keep it as it is instead wanting to reduce some LOC

The as is solution is more readable and easier to react to change, in comparison to the following:

```
  loginUser$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthStoreActions.loginUser, AuthStoreActions.registerUser),
      switchMap(action => {
        return this.authService[action.serviceMethod](action.userCredentials).pipe(
          map(() => AuthStoreActions.authSuccess({ navigateTo: "authentication/restaurant" })),
          catchError(error => of(AuthStoreActions.setError({ error })))
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

Comment: I understand your point. But it is not just for the line of code, if one needs to be changed the other one needs aswell, which has the draw back to remember to change that. For example the navigation route.